# XML phrase only language category SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, categories

I have earlier asked about feeding a XML feed to simplephp, but have now stumbled upon another problem. The feed have two language attributes (se and en), and I would like to feed out only the english results. From the english results I would like to feed out headline and location as and URL to download.

This is what I've got:
PHP:

```
    <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://fredrikbrolin.se/developm3nt/reports_presentations_feed_all.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->body->reports->report as $report)
           {
                 echo 'titel:'.$report->release_id.'<br/>';
            }
?>
```

Live link to XML feed: http://fredrikbrolin.se/developm3nt/reports_presentations_feed_all.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//body/reports/report[@language="se"]') as $report) {
    echo 'titel:'.$report->release_id.'<br/>';
}
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Comment: So I've got this code:
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://fredrikbrolin.se/developm3nt/reports_presentations_feed_all.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->xpath('//body/reports/report[@language="se"]') as $report) {
    echo 'titel:'.$report->release_id.'<br/>';
} ?>

But get a fatal error

EDIT: Got it to work, thanks a lot for the help!